# Autostart application/process

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

How is it possible to auto start my application or run a process when the user turns on the phone.
If you look at ex. Outlook WP7 included in the operating system then updates the icon so that you can see that there are new mail. This is a process in the background running.

But I've read a bit about this now, but can not find out that this is possible using the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) from Microsoft?

Is it not possible?? If possible, how does one do that?

**Notice: I do not want any solution that involves jailbreak.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, **it is not possible for 3rd party developers to run application in the background** as well as startup for Windows Phone 7.0.

What you can do is [update the Tile(icon)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltileschedule%28VS.92%29.aspx) using [Push Notification.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

UDPATE:

WP7 7.5 (Mango) has [Background Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202941%28VS.92%29.aspx) to mimic most of the behavior of background processing.

Comment: Lukas' advice is correct for 3rd party apps. The reason you may see other apps doing these things is because they are built by Microsoft or Carriers and capable of using more of the platforms capabilities than what is presently available in the 3rd party SDK.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for! +1 @Mick N: So you believe that there is no opportunity to do the same, or you can do the same as ex. Outlook by using the Push Notification? Will the phone call my service only when it is up. Or do I run a timer that checks the GUID to the phone on a regular basis? +1